# I am getting a blank page on my localhost 3000 on running npm start using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-start

I started making an a react app and added tag naming it with covid-19 tracker and on running npm start it perfectly showed the h1 heading i.e Covid 19 tracker but then I installed dependencies i.e

```
npm install @material-ui/core
```

and used some of its tags and then when I run npm start there was blank screen on my localhost:3000.

I added tags like    and imported them from "@material-ui/core" so that a dropdown box will be added on running npm start
but on ruuning npm start there was a blank screen ..nothing was shown..even the heading which was showing previously had gone .

I had pasted the image of App.js and localhost images below .

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0ax3.png)[localhosst screenshot after running dependency tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqzOl.png)
[image without using dependency tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri2N1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Material-UI/core is deprecated, it means that it is not compatible with current react version, therefore you can not use it on your project.

Answer (score 0):

As per Your first image you are calling react hook in class component or outside of functional component that is why that error is coming.

[rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

And for **Material-UI/core:**

So Material-UI/core is now deprecated so you can't use it inside your project.

[ref link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core/v/4.11.3-deprecations.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
```

add this line at the beginning of the **App.js** file.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use the updated MUI v5 by using the below command this will work

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

and then below is the component

```
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import { MenuItem } from "@mui/material";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: 100, margin: 50 }}>
      <FormControl >
        <Select variant="outlined" value="abc" >
          <MenuItem value="worldwide">Worldwide</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="worldwide">Option 1</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="worldwide">Option 2</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="worldwide">Option 3</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

for more info refer this link
https://mui.com/